# font-family when switching between languages (ie. english - french)

Tags: css, multilingual, font-family

Im implementing a language plugin on a site, you know the sort click and it changes all the content into Arabic, Russian.. ect (im aware that modern browsers have built in features for this, but we've chosen to go this way.)

What i was wandering is how we deal with fonts, if our normal site is running using

```
font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
```

Would it just fall back to the browser defaults if it couldn't render the new text in the above fonts?

Or is there a way of specifying fonts after the translation has taken place?

Answer (score 2):

When characters on a page cannot be found in the font listed first in the applicable `font-family` list, then browsers are expected to scan the list further and eventually, when needed, fall back to scanning other fonts in the system, in browser-dependent manner. However, browsers (especially IE) are known to fail here and, moreover, the process may result in a mix fonts, even characters from different fonts in a single word.

Thus, you should make a reasonable effort to ensure that any font listed in your `font-family` list is as such sufficient for the text of the page, at least for letters (special symbols may often be picked up from different fonts without stylistic mess). This is virtually impossible for a widget that translates into “any” language.

I suppose you are referring to the use of a service like Google Website Translator. In addition to producing generally bad translations for business purposes, it may mess up the markup of the page, possibly affecting font issues too. For example, it seems to insert rather pointless `font` markup which may prevent your font settings from working. Moreover, it does not properly set the `lang` attribute in the translation result (but leaves the original `lang` attribute!), so you cannot even expect browsers to use their language-specific defaults for fonts right.

Comment: i was leaning towards implemnting it using a some js like a click here for russian, chinese ect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you refer to when you say "im aware that modern browsers have built in features for this, but we've chosen to go this way" - browsers don't really provide language selection.

There is, however, a reusable JavaScript library that my team developed, that does this, and it takes care of fonts, too:

- https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.uls
- https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.webfonts

You can use it, or take ideas from it to your implementation.

Comment: if you visit a foreign site with chrome, it detects the language and then make a popup at the top of the page saying "this page is in ________ would you like to translate it to english" you can click yes and it will translate the page for you, like a built in google transalate.

Comment: I suppose the reference to features in modern browsers meant that they may have built-in features or add-ons that invoke Google Translator.